# Is it possible to pipeline Redis bloom filter commands?

Tags: redis, pipeline, bloom-filter

Redis has a module for working with bloom filters:

https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/Bloom_Commands/

Redis also allows for pipelining of commands:

https://redis.io/topics/pipelining

Specifically I am looking to check for the existence of a long list of items in a bloom filter. In the current implementation this requires me to issue N individual requests, one for each item in the checklist.

Looking for client code examples to pipeline a batch of `BF.EXISTS` calls in one network request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use pipeline. Instead, you can use [BF.MEXISTS](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/Bloom_Commands/#bfmexists) command to check multiple items:

```
BF.MEXISTS key item1 item2 item3
```

Comment: While you want to use BF.MEXISTS, as it would perform better than pipelining,  you can still pipeline with no issue.